# What are the differences between the different shot types?

Tags: age-of-wonders-3

I've noticed that on most ranged attacks they will have a description listed as either "Straight Shot" or "Arced Shot". I'm not sure how these two shot types differ on a mechanics level. I've also noticed that some units won't have any shot type listed under their ranged attack at all. I'm uncertain if there are more shot types that I'm unaware of.

What are the differences between the various shot types for a ranged attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ranged shots suffer from cover.  Arcing shots suffer less from cover.

> Cover:
>
> Units can use obstacles and other units in the Tactical Map as cover
>   to protect themselves from ranged abilities.  When an obstacle or unit
>   is in the line of fire of a ranged ability, it will do less damage. 
>   Some attacks are arching, this allows them to fire over obstacles more
>   easily, so they suffer a lesser penalty.

If an ability does not list Arced shot or Straight shot (such as Throw Net, Shock Breath, Fire Bomb and Fire Blunderbuss), then it is not a "ranged ability" (strict term).  Such an ability would be unaffected by cover.

Comment: Could you cite the source?

Comment: That's the in-game help.